# In a virtualenv pip installs globally and pip3 locally

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I've created a virtualenv called `venv` and activated it. When using `which` both `pip` and `pip3` point to the `venv/bin` folder. Yet when trying to install packages and listing them will there is a difference. When using `pip` all my global packages are listed and new packages are installed globally. With `pip3` the behavior is as expected containing everything within the virtual environment.

Here is a small console log:

```sh
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)$ which pip
./venv/bin/pip
(venv)$ which pip3
./venv/bin/pip3
(venv)$ pip list
SHOWS GLOBAL PACKAGES
(venv)$ pip3 list
SHOWS LOCAL PACKAGES
```

How do I get the correct with `pip` using the virtual environment?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with python 3.6.1 and pip 20.0.2.

Comment: Not an answer, but advice: don't use the _pip_ script directly, but use its executable module instead, so for example instead of `pip somecommand` (or `pip3`) run `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip somecommand` -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ -- Anyway, inside a virtual environment I see indeed no good reason why there should be any difference between the outputs of `pip list` and `pip3 list`. So maybe in your situation I would try to reinstall _pip_: `./venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade pip`.

Comment: @sinoroc Thank you for the tip. I will try this and see if this improves the situation.